# How LN() function works in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When do I calculate `LN(E2:E4)` in excel, it returns `#VALUE!` Error.

If I calculate the same formula as embedded formula like `INTERCEPT(LN(L1:L2),LN(M1:M2))` it returns `-21.3071` and also if i use SUM function `SUM(LN(L1:L2),LN(M1:M2))` it returns `#VALUE!` Error .

Please anyone share your opinion when `LN` formula returns `#VALUE!` Error. 
Also, whether `INTERCEPT` formula only returns value or else is there any other excel formula in which `LN` returns value?

Comment: Does `SUMPRODUCT` work instead?

Comment: What are the valus in E2:E4? And in L1:M2?

Comment: The values are L1 is 54,L2 is 45,M1 is 65,M2 is 67,E2 is 54,E3 is 45,E4 is 65.

Comment: Agreed with teylyn's answer. What do you want to do with the results of taking LN on each of the values in E2:E4? Sum them? Average them? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to read the help for the LN function, found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LN-function-81fe1ed7-dac9-4acd-ba1d-07a142c6118f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

> Syntax
>
> LN(number)
>
> The LN function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> Number    Required. The positive real number for which you want the
>   natural logarithm.

You seem to be passing a range, not a number.

Comment: yes. i could understand it.. that's why while passing the range , it returns #VALUE! error in excel.                                                                                 But while passing the same range in LN and embedded inside INTERCEPT formula , it returns value.My question is,whether INTERCEPT formula only returns value or else is there any other excel formula in which LN returns value?